# Как установить значение в поле формы по умолчанию в Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте, делаю поля для редактирования объекта в angular, столкнулся с проблемой, когда уже переданные поля в value не обрабатываются при сабмите формы, точнее обрабатываются только когда в них вносишь правки, вот пример, как с таким бороться?

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
  <input formControlName="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Название" value="{{ content?.title }}"/> 
   <input formControlName="body" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Контент" value="{{ content?.body }}"/> 
  <input type="submit" value="Редактировать"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: попробуй в самом инстансе класса работать с формой `this.myForm.get('title').setValue = yourAsyncValue` тк у тебя Data-driven форма

Comment: Помогло, очень сильно благодарен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При работе с **Data-Driven** формами для изменения значений формы надо обращаться к экземпляру формы созданном в классе компонента и изменять значения через `setValue()`. В данном примере это будет выглядеть как:

```
this.myForm.get('title').setValue = yourAsyncValue;
```